# How do I keep an image inside a div with a set width and height, but keep the rest of the image hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

It's kind of difficult to word... So I made a picture!

[image]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lfyudgGauy1qboy47o1_r1_400.png))</sub>

I tried giving the div that has a set width and height overflow:hidden; but that didn't work... I searched all over and I probably just didn't word it right.

I gave the tag 'javascript' just because this may require javascript, if it doesn't please comment and tell me to remove the tag! Thankyou!

HTML

```
<div class="trigger" id="photoTile"> 
<img id="photoSmall" src="{PhotoURL-500}">
<h5>Photo</h5>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{MonthNumber} {DayOfMonth} {Year}
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{block:NoteCount}{NoteCount} <img    
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/2Z0lf9580/heart.png">{/block:NoteCount}
</div>
```

CSS

```
.trigger {
margin:0 20px 20px 0;
float:left;
background:#6f7f7a;
width:115px;
height:105px;
padding:5px;
}

#photoTile {
width:115px;
height:105px;
overflow:hidden;
background:none;
}

#photoSmall {
opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: If you post the CSS and/or HTML you tried, somebody may be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the image in a `<div>` with fixed height and width, and "overflow: hidden", most definitely will crop an included `<img>`.

*edit* [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xYKNz/) is a jsfiddle showing an image much larger than 100x100 in a 100x100 `<div>` styled with "overflow: hidden". Here's the CSS for the `<div>`:

```
#w { height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
```

I didn't have to do anything interesting with the `<img>` at all; it's just lexically nested inside the `<div>`.

Comment: Wow thanks! I think there may be a problem in MY situation, however. On the page that I'm using this http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com/ There are other things inside the box.

Comment: which box are we talking about on that site?  is it the "thumbnail" box on the main page?

Comment: The boxes that say Photo in them, it has a set id along with a global class so I can seperatley remove the background from only photo boxes so I can set the index of the photo being displayed as the background of the text.

Comment: Well as of right now, I don't see "overflow: hidden" on any of those.  Is it possible that there's something as simple as a typo in the CSS file?  It helps a lot to use Firebug or the Chrome debugger, or even the IE8 debugger, to look around at the *actual* styles for elements.

Comment: Sorry, didn't save. roseannebarr.tumblr.com

Comment: Ah - well here's one problem: you're trying to use the "id" value "photoTile" for many different elements. Each "id" value on a page has to be **unique** - that's why it's an "id".  Perhaps you should make "photoTile" a class instead.

Comment: I cant because "trigger" is the websites 'global' controller of each block.

Comment: Well, it's just a fact that trying to re-use an "id" value will cause you **all sorts** of weird problems. It's invalid markup, and I suspect it's a reason your attempts to control the style aren't working.

Comment: I tried just making the class="trigger photoTile" but then I can't remove the background color of phototile, plus it doesn't work :(

Comment: On the generated page I'm actually not, it's Tumblr that pulls multiple images from a database (blog input) so it's this part <img id="photoSmall" src="{PhotoURL-500}"> {PhotoURL-500} is the picture(s) that your seeing.

Comment: Ah well **another** problem, and one which **really** explains what's going on, is that the images in those "tile" boxes have "position: absolute" set (in the "#photoSmall" CSS). Take that away. That will cause them to cover up the text, but that should be fixable.

Comment: Ok I tried that, still didn't work. I also tried setting a specific height because the text inside of THAT specific "trigger" box goes below the photo (it's meant to be the background) so I thought about margin-bottom to bring up the text inside the box but didn't bother since the beginning part failed.

Comment: WAIT!!!!!! I got it to work, but now the text went back behind the photo :( I have the photo set to z-index:-1;

Comment: Yes, that "z-index" won't have any effect. Maybe see what happens if you use "position: relative" instead of "position: absolute" (I'll try that too)

Comment: You know, what you *could* do is have the images show up, and instead of making *them* be "position: absolute", put them in `<div>` wrappers that have "overflow: hidden", the right size, **and** "position: absolute".

Comment: No go on the position relative. I will try the other idea :)

Comment: A little extra coding but I got it! Thanks for your help Pointy! If I run into a problem I will be back but for now I think I have it. One problem I encountered is I ran back into the original problem of the photo being behind trigger, so if I set trigger with a background color the photo is hidden. I tried setting photo's class as trigger photoTile and background:none; but it didn't work. I think I will just give each tile it's own special class along with trigger and style their backgrounds and not the photos.

Comment: Cool - glad it worked out.  Things like that can be a real pain, especially when you don't have 100% control over everything.